# biblatex-dm.cfg not found by bundledoc

Tags: biblatex, archiving, bundledoc

Considering this MWE

```
\RequirePackage{snapshot}
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{filecontents,biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @misc{anything,
  author={A. Anyone}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
 \chapter{My document}
This is my text
\end{document}
```

In the `.dep`-file there is the line

```
  *{file}   {biblatex-dm.cfg}{0000/00/00 v0.0}
```

When I use the `.dep`-file with `bundledoc` I get the error

```
bundledoc: "kpsewhich -progname=latex $BDINPUTS" (BDINPUTS="biblatex-dm.cfg") failed to find biblatex-dm.cfg
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I made a bug report: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/719

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ulrike Fischer has rightly (I believe) reported this as a bug https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/719. The issue is that even files that were not found are added to the list of used files with `\@addtofilelist`. A fix is present in `biblatex` 3.11, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/721.

In the meantime you can use

```
\protected\long\def\blx@inputonce#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \ifcsundef{blx@file@#1}
    {\blx@info@noline{Trying to load #2..}%
     \IfFileExists{#1}
       {\blx@info@noline{... file '#1' found}%
        #3\@@input\@filef@und#4#5%
        \listxadd\blx@list@req@stat{#1}%
        \@addtofilelist{#1}}
       {\blx@info@noline{... file '#1' not found}#6}%
     \global\cslet{blx@file@#1}\@empty}
    {#5}}
```

as a workaround. This patch needs to be applied directly in `biblatex.sty` to the original definition of `\blx@inputonce`, in practice that means you need to modify `biblatex.sty`. Since this might be a little impractical Ulrike offered another work-around

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@filelist{biblatex-dm.cfg,}{}{}{\fail}
\makeatletter
```

This simply removes `biblatex-dm.cfg` from the list of used files.